# How manipulate a pandas data frame that has been grouped by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm struggling to understand what kind of data type I get after applying groupby() on a data frame.
I have an initial table of video games entities columns (developer, platform, sales, etc).
I want to see how many sales have been from each developer so I grouped it by developer and summed sales with this line:

```
dev_sales = df.groupby('Developer')['EU_Sales'].sum()
```

And now it looks like this:

```
Developer
10tacle Studios, Fusionsphere Systems    0.02
1C, 1C Company                           0.03
1C, Ino-Co, 1C Company                   0.00
1C: Maddox Games                         0.08
1C:Ino-Co                                0.00
                                         ... 
id Software, Raven Software              0.52
n-Space                                  1.00
neo Software                             0.19
odenis studio                            0.00
syn Sophia                               0.84
```

Now what I want to do is to filter this table to only the top 10 (like using nlargest() on a data frame) but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I'll appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
dev_sales.nlargest(10)
```

Or:

```
dev_sales.sort_values().tail(10)
```